# getting NullInjectorError while trying to access variable of a component from another component

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to access a variable in my footer component which I have declared in a navbar component in my project, but when I am trying to access it by using an import statement I am getting NullInjectorError

I have tried including it in entryComponents Array in app.module.ts

```js
export class NavbarComponent implements OnInit {
direction: string = "left";
```

```js
import { NavbarComponent } from './../navbar/navbar.component';

export class FooterComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(public navbar: NavbarComponent) { }
```

I am getting an error and unable to access that variable

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[FooterComponent -> NavbarComponent]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[FooterComponent -> NavbarComponent]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for NavbarComponent!
NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[FooterComponent -> NavbarComponent]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[FooterComponent -> NavbarComponent]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for NavbarComponent!
    at NullInjector.get (core.js:778)
    at resolveToken (core.js:2564)
    at tryResolveToken (core.js:2490)
    at StaticInjector.get (core.js:2353)
    at resolveToken (core.js:2564)
    at tryResolveToken (core.js:2490)
    at StaticInjector.get (core.js:2353)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (core.js:26403)
    at NgModuleRef_.get (core.js:27491)
    at resolveDep (core.js:28021)
    at resolvePromise (zone-evergreen.js:797)
    at resolvePromise (zone-evergreen.js:754)
    at zone-evergreen.js:858
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:391)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:34182)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:390)
    at Zone.runTask (zone-evergreen.js:168)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone-evergreen.js:559)
```

Comment: You're trying to use `NavbarComponent` as a provider, which is not! How do you intend to use `NavbarComponent` in `FooterComponent `? Also, see [Component Interaction](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont access a property from parent component through injection. Use `@Input` instead:

In navbar.component.html :

```
<your-footer-selector [direction] = "direction"></your-footer-selector>
```

In your footer.component.ts:

```
export class FooterComponent implements OnInit {
 @Input() direction;
 ngOnInit(){
  console.log(this.direction)
 }
}
```

I suggest to read more about it at Angular document on [Component Interaction](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction)